# What is the minimum required Android API level for Smack 4.1?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I have been creating an android chat app and planning to use Smack 4.1, as the android XMPP library.
Before proceeding i just want to confirm that Smack 4.1 is supported well on all versions of android starting from Android 4.0 as that would be the minimum OS i would like my app to support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum required Android API Level for Smack 4.1 is **8**. This means Smack 4.1 is able to run on Android devices [running Android 2.2 or later](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels).

For the curious, [the Android API level required by Smack is defined in Smack's `version.gradle` file](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/cd3692f329d8e2cb3e9d128c6a5cd4733147d981/version.gradle#L6).

Answer (score 0):

Yes 4.1 will work on all version of android be aware Smack < 4.1 does not work on Android, mostly

I would suggest you to rather go with Asmack, I have developed a chatting app before with Asmack and have started new app recently. Asmack internally uses Smack API's.